# The [rational-numbers] and [irrational-numbers] tags

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-wikis, tag-management

Many questions are about both [rational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rational-numbers) and [irrational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irrational-numbers), e.g. determining whether a number is rational or irrational. Some of them are tagged [rational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rational-numbers), some [irrational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irrational-numbers) and some have both:

- [Both tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=[irrational-numbers]+[rational-numbers]+is%3Aquestion) (104)
- [Only (rational-numbers) but contain 'irrational'](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=[rational-numbers]+irrational+-[irrational-numbers]+is%3Aquestion) (32)
- [Only (irrational-numbers) but contain 'rational'](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=[irrational-numbers]+rational+-[rational-numbers]+is%3Aquestion) (211)

Simply merging them into something like [rationals-irrationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rationals-irrationals) would be a bit crude, but also incorrect as there are questions focussing on only one of them; e.g.:

- [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1203583) asks to find rational solutions to an equation and thus has hardly anything to do with irrational numbers.
- [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136665) typical question is best tagged with [irrational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irrational-numbers) only.
  If the OP would have asked if anything changes when $\alpha$ is rational, this would have been an example of a question to be tagged with both.

We have to do *something* about this issue, but what?

> **Proposal:** Introduce a [rationality-testing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rationality-testing) tag for questions about determining whether a number is rational, and related problems such as determining whether $(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)^{200}$ is integer or e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1223725) question.
>   **Why?** Most [rational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rational-numbers) or [irrational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irrational-numbers) questions seem to be about determining whether a certain number is rational. It would be great to have them separated from other [rational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rational-numbers) and [irrational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irrational-numbers) questions. Filtering these with a new tag copes with the major part of the questions having both tags.

I think by doing this the two tags become almost separated (i.e. few questions in their intersection).

What do you think?

---

**Some practical issues with the proposed solution**

- Executing this plan would involve adding 'For questions about determining whether a certain number is rational, use the (rationality-testing) tag instead.' to the tag descriptions.
- Any better names for the new tag? *[rationals-irrationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rationals-irrationals) has been replaced by [rationality-testing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rationality-testing) in this post.*
- It would involve much re-tagging, unless we can work around it in a clever way: as most questions would fit in [rationality-testing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rationality-testing), we might: (I'm not sure if this is possible)

  - (Temporarily) merge [rational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rational-numbers) and [irrational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irrational-numbers) into [rationality-testing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rationality-testing)
  - Re-tag the questions that do not fit in [rationality-testing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rationality-testing) (which I think aren't many) with [rational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rational-numbers) and [irrational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irrational-numbers)

Comment: If you take the union of the tags, wouldn't it be more appropriate to call it [tag:real-numbers]? :-P

Comment: Given the edit, I'm in support of the request, I think, but before it can be put into action we need a better (read: less ambiguous) name to replace [tag:rationals-irrationals].

Comment: Perhaps ([tag:rationality])?

Comment: Removing the word "numbers" introduces ambiguity, IMO. The adjective "rational" is used for a lot of things...

Comment: Perhaps [tag:rationality-test] would be clearer?

Comment: I went trough the 150 most recent [tag:irrational-numbers] questions. 87 of them would fall under the new tag. I can make a list of them somewhere if that would be useful (I guess so). I did the same for [tag:rational-numbers] (but I didn't go that far yet) and at first sight it seems only a few of them fall under the new tag.

Comment: @barto [tag:rationality-test] seems reasonable; perhaps [tag:rationality-testing] would be more in line with existing tags. Naturally, a synonym [tag:irrationality-testing] would be in order.

Comment: If we really want 'number' in it, we could make it [tag:rational-number-testing] (23 characters, so there's room to add 'ir'). I don't find that necessary but it _will_ make the tag easier to find among tag suggestions.

Comment: Not sure if we want [tag:transcendence-testing] too.

Comment: So basically you seek a *rational* way to tag these questions? :) Sorry, just had to get that out of my system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there seems to be support for the new tag, let's try to write and rewrite the **tag excerpts**:

> **[rationality-testing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rationality-testing)** [excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1229723/revisions)
> For questions on determining whether a number is rational, and related problems. If applicable, use this tag instead of (rational-numbers) and (irrational-numbers). Consider adding a tag (radicals) or (logarithms), depending on what the question is about.
>
> **[rational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rational-numbers)** [excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/255493/revisions)
> **Old excerpt:** For questions on rational numbers, numbers that can be expressed as the quotient or fraction $\frac pq$ of two integers.
> **New:** Questions about numbers expressible as the quotient of two integers. For questions on determining whether a number is rational, use the (rationality-testing) tag instead.
>
> **[irrational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irrational-numbers)** [excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/43671/revisions)
> **Old:** Numbers not expressible as a ratio of two integers. Examples: $\sqrt{2},\phi,e,\pi,\zeta(3)$. Some of them are algebraic ($\sqrt{2},\phi$) and some transcendental ($e,\pi$).
> **New:** Questions about numbers not expressible as the quotient of two integers. For questions on determining whether a number is irrational, use the (rationality-testing) tag instead.

Feel free to discuss and edit.

Comment: I propose to drop the examples in the [tag:irrational-numbers] wiki. Maybe we could just add _"Some of them are algebraic and some are transcendental."_

Comment: I was not sure where to put _"Some of them are algebraic and some are transcendental."_ so I have (temporarily) removed it.

Comment: User [Jean-Claude Arbaut](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/43608) had some remarks, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/388788) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/388787).